# How to make a Docker architecture with Traefik and Snort3

Tags: docker, security, traefik, snort

I'm trying to find a way to do the following architecture with Docker, Traefik and Snort3.

[image: Architecture]

I need to understand what it is possible to do with this two systems to make that secure.

In the left image Snort3 is in the middle of the architecture and in the right image is as a side load of Traefik.

I don't know what is possible and best practices for this and trying also to find a possibility for a demo and materials for it.

Like an example of a docker file with same network which can explain this architecture.

The API in this case is NodeJS but the most important is how to place Snort3 with Docker between a Traefik container and the API container

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "to make that secure"?

Comment: I tried only theory as I never used Snort3 and I need an idea or help how I can introduce that in a sytem where there is Traefik based on Docker containers and network. Secure because I have to add Snort3 to that Architecture schema to secure the sytem. I was unable to find any Docker example on Google of Treafik with Snort3.

Comment: In addition to comment above, why must snort be in one of those 2 places? Why not in front of traefik?

Comment: I don't know, was proposed to me in this way by a manger but why in front?
Can you explain me please so I can understand the idea :)